# .Net EF Core - Include option not working for nested relationship class/table

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I'm working with a .NET 6 API project. I'm using Entity Framework Core with SQL Server.

I have 4 tables

```
User, Role, UserCredentialMapping, UserRoleMapping
```

as shown below as classes) for user management.

```
[Table("User")]
public class User
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } = false;

    [Required]
    public long CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public virtual ICollection<UserCredentialMapping> UserCredentialMappings { get; set; } = new List<UserCredentialMapping>();

    public virtual ICollection<UserRoleMapping> UserRoleMappings { get; set; } = new List<UserRoleMapping>();
}

[Table("Role")]
public class Role
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long RoleId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } = false;

    [Required]
    public long CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public virtual ICollection<UserRoleMapping> UserRoleMappings { get; set; }
}

[Table("UserCredentialMapping")]
public class UserCredentialMapping
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long UserCredentialId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public long UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public long CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public long UpdatedBy { get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual User Users { get; set; } = new User();
}

[Table("UserRoleMapping")]
public class UserRoleMapping
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long UserRoleMappingId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public long UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public long RoleId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } = false;

    [Required]
    public long CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;


    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual User Users { get; set; } = new User();

    [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
    public virtual Role Roles { get; set; } = new Role();
}
```

And My DbContext class like below for the Code first approach.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserCredentialMapping> UserCredentialMappings { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserRoleMapping> UserRoleMappings { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasData(new List<User>
            {
                new User()
                {
                    UserId = 1,
                    Name = "Mano",
                    Email = "mano@gmail.com",
                    Address = "Mano address",
                    MobileNo = "1234567890",
                    IsActive = true,
                    CreatedBy = 1,
                    CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                },
                new User()
                {
                    UserId = 2,
                    Name = "Hari",
                    Email = "Hari@gmail.com",
                    Address = "Hari address",
                    MobileNo = "5432167890",
                    IsActive = true,
                    CreatedBy = 1,
                    CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                }
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<UserCredentialMapping>().HasData(new List<UserCredentialMapping>
            {
                new UserCredentialMapping()
                {
                    UserCredentialId = 1,
                    UserId = 1,
                    UserName = "Mano",
                    Password = "Mano",
                    IsActive = true,
                    CreatedBy = 1,
                    CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                },
                new UserCredentialMapping()
                {
                    UserCredentialId = 2,
                    UserId = 2,
                    UserName = "Hari",
                    Password = "Hari",
                    IsActive = true,
                    CreatedBy = 1,
                    CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                }
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().HasData(new List<Role>
            {
                new Role()
                {
                    RoleId = 1,
                    Name = "Admin",
                    IsActive = true,
                    CreatedBy = 1,
                    CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                },
                new Role()
                {
                    RoleId = 2,
                    Name = "User",
                    IsActive = true,
                    CreatedBy = 1,
                    CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                }
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<UserRoleMapping>().HasData(new List<UserRoleMapping>
            {
                new UserRoleMapping()
                {
                    UserRoleMappingId = 1,
                    UserId = 1,
                    RoleId = 1,
                    IsActive = true,
                    CreatedBy = 1,
                    CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                },
                new UserRoleMapping()
                {
                    UserRoleMappingId = 2,
                    UserId = 2,
                    RoleId = 2,
                    IsActive = true,
                    CreatedBy = 1,
                    CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                }
            });

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

While I'm trying to execute below EF query, getting 2 records.

```
_context.UserCredentialMappings
        .Include(x => x.Users)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.UserRoleMappings)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserName == UserName && x.Password == Password);
```

But I need role details too, in the same object, so I have included `Select(s => s.Roles)` like this:

```
_context.UserCredentialMappings
        .Include(x => x.Users)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.UserRoleMappings)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Select(s => s.Roles))
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserName == UserName && x.Password == Password);
```

While executing the above, the EF query is throwing an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The expression 'x.AsQueryable().Select(d => d.Roles)' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations. For more information on including related data, see [http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.'](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.%27)

I can't seem to understand want went wrong with this code.

I tried:

```
_context.UserCredentialMappings
        .Include(x => x.Users)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.UserRoleMappings)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Select(s => s.Roles))
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserName == UserName && x.Password == Password);
```

I'm expecting to get 2 rows with role details.

Comment: `Select` is not supported in `Include`, see [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include). Why do you want to use a `Select` here, is `.Include(x => x.Roles)` not working?

Comment: No mapping for `.Include(x => x.Roles)`.  `.ThenInclude(x => x.Roles)` throwing compiler error, because `x=>x` is a ICollection object. Also I have tried with .Include('Roles') but getting same invalid operation exception

Comment: Also I have tried with `.Include("Users.UserRoleMappings.Roles")` but getting same invalid operation exception

Comment: Have you tried with other solutions rather than eager loading?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/

Comment: @colinD Include with Select was valid syntax, however in EF (not EF core): 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data. There was no ThenInclude, so it would be something like .Include(x => x.Users.Select(xx => xx.UserRoleMappings.Select(xxx => xxx.Roles))). Not sure if it actually works with 2 nested selects, but with one for sure.

Comment: Good to know @Maxim, however if I'm right the question is about EF Core, so `.ThenInclude(x => x.Roles)` should work.

Comment: @colinD yes, you are absolutely right. And I also think that ThenInclude should work here. It was just a side note - Select syntax felt somehow not totally wrong, I remembered using it at some point, so I started looking. Just posted for info, author was probably mixing EF and EF Core tutorials.

Comment: @manokaranps is there any chance you might be using StorageContext instead of DbContext?

Comment: Thanks for your comments @Maxim and @ColinD, I have added the `DbContext` class in the above of my questions section. Kindly refer and help me to fix on this.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @Maxim and @ColinD, I have tried with Eager & Explicit loading but `x.Roles` intelligence not coming up for the following `Eager: .Include(x => x.Users.UserRoleMappings.Roles) & Explicit: .Collection(b => b.Users.UserRoleMappings.Roles)` . I can able to write like `Eager: .Include(x => x.Users.UserRoleMappings.Select(s => s.Roles)) & Explicit: .Collection(b => b.Users.UserRoleMappings.Select(s => s.Roles))` due to UserRoleMappings is a ICollection object. Also I have added the `DbContext` class in the above of my questions section. Kindly refer & help me on this.

Comment: That's right, about the collection. I reread your comments, and I'll ask again, coz I'm not 100% sure: did you actually try `.Include(c => c.Users).ThenInclude(c => c.UserRoleMappings).ThenInclude(c => c.Roles)` and if yes, which error did you get?

Comment: I can't able to run `.ThenInclude(c => c.Roles`, because it's showing intelligence error while writing coding

Comment: Can you make a screenshot of your "intelligence error"? I've copied the code you pasted, and this line does not produce any errors and compiles: `var result = await ctx.UserCredentialMappings.Include(x => x.Users).ThenInclude(x => x.UserRoleMappings).ThenInclude(x => x.Roles).ToListAsync();`

Comment: you are right @Maxim. I tried with `.Include(x => x.Users.UserRoleMappings.Roles)` this shows intelligence error. But yours code `var result = await ctx.UserCredentialMappings.Include(x => x.Users).ThenInclude(x => x.UserRoleMappings).ThenInclude(x => x.Roles).ToListAsync();` working fine. Also thanks for taking of my questions.

Comment: Also got one error: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The seed entity for entity type 'UserCredentialMapping' cannot be added because it has the navigation 'Users' set. To seed relationships,  add the entity seed to 'UserCredentialMapping' and specify the foreign key values {'UserId'}. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the involved property values.'
`.

Comment: For above error I have made changes on the **UserCredentialMapping** class - ```public virtual User Users { get; set; } = new User(); --> removed = new User();``` & in **UserRoleMapping** class - ```public virtual User Users { get; set; } = new User(); --> removed  = new User();
    public virtual Role Roles { get; set; } = new Role(); --> removed  = new Role();```

Comment: Many thanks for all your support.

Comment: Glad to hear the problem is solved! I've summarized all the comments in an answer. You may now mark it as accepted if you think it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should chain `ThenInclude` like this: `var result = await ctx.UserCredentialMappings.Include(x => x.Users).ThenInclude(x => x.UserRoleMappings).ThenInclude(x => x.Roles).ToListAsync();` Each `ThenInclude` works on the result of the previous one.

The syntax you initially tried with `.ThenInclude(x => x.Select(s => s.Roles))` is not valid, although similar syntax was previously used in full EF `Include` method to load multiple levels when `ThenInclude` was not available, e.g. `Include(c => c.Users.Select(cc => cc.UserRoleMappings))`. This is no longer valid in EF Core.